# JQuery: How can I select all descendant nodes of an element that have a certain css class on them?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given a DOM element e, I would like to select all descendants that have class='foo'. How can I do this in jquery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [**`.find()`**](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(e).find('.foo')
```

<sub>(The documentation is your friend :))</sub>

Comment: or `$(e).children('.foo')`, depending on what you want (the title and the description of the OP are inconsistent)

Answer (score -2):

You can use some thing like `$(this).childrens().hasClass('foo')`, I will try to give the exact answer, if I know the exact query.. please try to be more precise in your question.